# Onclick in td - access next cells

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using a table to display items, an onclick event on cell[0] should output (alert) the data from cell[1] and cell[2].

I'm not sure with which approach I could access them.

Here is my code so far
http://jsfiddle.net/5uua7eyx/3/

Perhaps there is a way to use my variable input

***HTML***

```
<table id="items">
    <tr>
        <td onclick="ClickPic(this)">Picture0</td>
        <td>Name0</td>
        <td>Price0</td>
    </tr>

        <tr>
        <td onclick="ClickPic(this)">Picture1</td>
        <td>Name1</td>
        <td>Price1</td>
    </tr>         
</table>
```

***JS***

```
function ClickPic(e) {
    "use strict";
    var input = e.target;
    alert("Clicked!");
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing `this`, which represents the element clicked, not the event object.

All you need to do is use the parameter to get the sibling `.cells` from the `.parentNode`, then use the `elem.cellIndex` to figure out the next indices:

```js
function ClickPic(elem) {
    "use strict";
    var cells = elem.parentNode.cells;
    var currIdx = elem.cellIndex;
    alert(cells[currIdx + 1].textContent + " " + cells[currIdx + 2].textContent);
}
```

```html
<table id="items">
    <tr>
        <td onclick="ClickPic(this)">Picture0</td>
        <td>Name0</td>
        <td>Price0</td>
    </tr>

        <tr>
        <td onclick="ClickPic(this)">Picture1</td>
        <td>Name1</td>
        <td>Price1</td>
    </tr>         
</table>
x
```

If you know the index numbers will always be `1` and `2`, then you can shorten it.

```
    alert(cells[1].textContent + " " + cells[2].textContent);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I changed the jsfiddle document for the alert
And if I want to store the content - something like this 'var Name = cells[1].innerHTML;' or with textContent?

Comment: I would use `.textContent` if you only want to get the text. But yes, that's how you'd store it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your js function to something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function ClickPic(e) {
                var s = '';
                $(e).siblings().each(function() {
                s = s + ',' + $(this).text()
```

});

```
                alert(s);
```

}